# How to implement a pagination in a GET method using express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, pagination

I was interested in how I can implement a pagination system in a GET method, but I do not know how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

In the following json scheme I want you to show me information related to the page, for example: Actual page , Next page , Total page, etc...

I want to refer to the page using &page=1 in the url

**Json**

```
{
  "animes": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "id": "",
      "poster": "",
      "type": "",
      "synopsis": "",
      "state": ""
    },
   ]
}
```

**Router**

```js
import * as scraper from './scraper';
import * as express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/latest', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  scraper.lastAnimesAdded()
    .then(animes => {
      res.status(200).json({
        animes
      });
    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err)
    });
});
```

**Paginator**

```js
export const paginator = (items, page, per_page) => {
  var page = page || 1,
  per_page = per_page || 10,
  offset = (page - 1) * per_page,

  paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page),
  total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page),

  paginContent = {
    page: page,
    per_page: per_page,
    pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : null,
    next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : null,
    total: items.length,
    total_pages: total_pages,
    data: paginatedItems
  };
  console.log("Paginate Item: ", paginatedItems);
  console.log("Pagin Content: ", paginContent);
  const total = paginContent.total;
  return paginContent.data;
};
```

Comment: What have you done so far? You'll need to show us what you've tried and we can try to help you.

Comment: yes, have something

Comment: The problem I'm having is that it only shows me 20 data from the array, no matter what endpoint path it uses. It is 10 data per page, in total 2 pages.

And I have an endpoint that has more than 100 data, so I'm supposed to get a paginator for more than 10 pages and not 2

Comment: Here I have an endpoint of my api: https://ryuanime-api.chrismichael.now.sh/api/v1/movies/1

If you notice, that route has more than 5 pages with data, 10 data per page.


Now with my implementation of paginator only shows me the first 20 pages, 2 pages in all of which is incorrect.

Comment: It seems to me this is essentially working; if I change the last value in the URL there seem to be 17 pages. Are you just trying to do a router rewrite?

Comment: @BenHulan Correct, what I want to achieve is from the router to use ?Page=1

Comment: I think you just replace `latest` with the appropriate string. I haven't used Express in several years but it should be something like this:  `router.get('?Page=:id',`